# Rotating a skybox in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a skybox created using:

```
skybox_path = 'images/skybox_images/';
skybox_name = 'Stars_2';

var urls = [
            skybox_path + skybox_name + '_right1.png',
            skybox_path + skybox_name + '_left2.png',
            skybox_path + skybox_name + '_top3.png',
            skybox_path + skybox_name + '_bottom4.png',
            skybox_path + skybox_name + '_front5.png',
            skybox_path + skybox_name + '_back6.png'
          ];

var cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls); // load textures
cubemap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

var shader = THREE.ShaderLib['cube']; // init cube shader from built-in lib
shader.uniforms['tCube'].value = cubemap; // apply textures to shader

// create shader material
var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
  fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
  vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
  uniforms: shader.uniforms,
  depthWrite: false,
  side: THREE.BackSide
});


// create skybox mesh
var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.CubeGeometry(1000, 1000, 1000),
  skyBoxMaterial
);

scene.add(skybox);
```

This works fine, however I now wish to rotate the skybox within the animation loop.

If I use:

```
skybox.rotation.x += 0.01;
```

within a render loop, the skybox cube rotates, but the textures don't.  I get a very interesting and insightful effect with the cube moving but the textures remaining fixed, but this isn't my desired effect, I'd like the textures to move with the cube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, the method I posted in my question for creating the skybox needs to be changed if we want to animate its orientation without unusual perspective effects.

The method to create a skybox which enables it to be rotated is as follows:

```
    var urls = [
            skybox_path + skybox_name + '_right1.png',
            skybox_path + skybox_name + '_left2.png',
            skybox_path + skybox_name + '_top3.png',
            skybox_path + skybox_name + '_bottom4.png',
            skybox_path + skybox_name + '_front5.png',
            skybox_path + skybox_name + '_back6.png'
          ];

 var materialArray = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
   map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( urls[i] ),
   side: THREE.BackSide
  }));

 var skyGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 5000, 5000, 5000 );
 var skyMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materialArray );
 var skybox = new THREE.Mesh( skyGeometry, skyMaterial );
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Hello,

I appreciate this question as I am doing the same exact thing. I went from this answer to the shader in an effort to increase my performance. Is their no other way to do it? I would prefer to use shaders and keep everything on the GPU.

Comment: Hi, it may be best to ask your own question on this directly on SE.  I hate to say it, but I found Three.js support lacking when I was developing with it, so I moved onto other projects for the time being using OpenGL.

Comment: Damn. Yeah there's like six people on SO who answer these questions regularly and that's about it. Thanks for the heads up.