# How can I rotate a background or skybox in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I need to be able to rotate the background by a specific number of degrees on the x, y, or z axes. How can I do this?

- There's no rotation axis property for `scene.background`.
- If I create a box, I can only see the images on the outside, not the inside, and it moves relative to the camera. It needs to never move, even if my distance and scale are both maxed out (like 1e+16). Bad things happen when the render far plane is too high.
- Also, I would prefer not to have to pre-mirror all skybox textures if possible.
- The three.js fundamentals page says nothing about this.
- Other posts are 5+ years old, probably before built-in support for backgrounds.

If I set `material.depthWrite = false` that just makes something appear behind everything, but that doesn't keep it from moving, etc.

Sorry I have very limited knowledge of three.js, as this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: It's not possible to do this yet however there is the following feature request: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/16328

Comment: any alternative? i can't even find a way to rotate an HDRI image and save the rotated file

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I modified/updated the code from this post [Rotating a skybox in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787382/rotating-a-skybox-in-three-js) and it's working right now with only minor perspective effects (the background starts to move a tiny bit if i zoom out all the way, which is a massive zoom level)...

the background cube will be scaled to skyLength.
skyHyp is used to set the maximum viewing distance.
pxmICRF = Postive X, mirrored, International Celestial Reference Frame. it's a jpg file in base64.
this variable name describes the image, NOT where it will go in three.js CGI coordinates.

## ICRF to THREE.js CGI mapping:

- +x ICRF === +x CGI
- -x ICRF === -x CGI
- +y ICRF === -z CGI
- -y ICRF === +z CGI
- +z ICRF === +y CGI
- -z ICRF === -y CGI

The conversion is a 90 degree rotation on the x axis.

all you need to know is the array order of left, right, top, bottom, center, back. "center" means that top and bottom need to be rotated to match above and below center.

```
let skyLength = 1e7;
let skyHyp = Math.sqrt(skyLength**2 + skyLength**2) + 1;

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    25,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.001,
    skyHyp
);

//           LEF      RIG      TOP      BOT      CEN      BAK
//           pxmCGI   nxmCGI   pymCGI   nymCGI   pzCGI    nzCGI
let walls = [pxmICRF, nxmICRF, pzmICRF, nzmICRF, nymICRF, pymICRF];
let materialArray = [];
for (let index = 0; index < 6; index++) {
  let texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(walls[index]);
  materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture,
    side: THREE.BackSide
  }));
}
let geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
skybox = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialArray);
skybox.scale.set(skyLength, skyLength, skyLength);
skybox.rotation.x = - 23.44 * Math.PI / 180;
scene.add(skybox);
```

now i can rotate the skybox as-needed..
i will note that using `.rotation.x` in some cases is unpredictable. when i need to be serious about rotating something, i use rotateOnAxis() and rotateOnWorldAxis().