# Is it possible to rotate a cube environment map 180 degrees around Y axis?

Tags: three.js, ar.js

I'd like to rotate a cube map about `Y` axis by 180 degrees.

```js
scene = new THREE.Scene();

scene.background = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()
                                      .setPath( '/path/to/my/docs/' )
                                      .load( [ 'posX.jpg', 'negX.jpg', 
                                               'posY.jpg', 'negY.jpg', 
                                               'posZ.jpg', 'negZ.jpg' ] );
// this doesn't work
scene.background.rotation.y = Math.PI;
```

**How can I do that**?

Comment: It is not possible, `scene.background` doesn't have a rotation attribute. Although [this identical question has proposed a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582271/how-can-i-rotate-a-background-or-skybox-in-three-js), you could give it a try. Alternatively, if you need the rotation to only happen once, you can use [this online CubeMap creator](https://matheowis.github.io/HDRI-to-CubeMap/) that takes an equirectangular img, you apply the rotation you want, then it outputs 6 cubeTexture faces, permanently rotated.

Comment: Thanks @Marquizzo didnt realise by draging on the cube map preview, it saves in that position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pity but in Three.js I have no possibility to rotate my cube map using `rotation` parameter:

```
scene.background.rotation.y = Math.PI;
```

### Solution

The simplest solution in my case (I want to rotate it around Y axis) is to rename 4 images that form the sides of the cube map to reorient that cube (skybox) 180 degrees.

**We must remember that by default Three.js `Camera` looks towards `-Z` direction**.

Look at these pictures. Left image depicts a default 6-image-placement to form a cube map. Right image represents 180-degrees-about-Y-axis reoriented cube.

[image]

### Renaming process

So, for reorientation you just need to rename 4 source files. Here's a table showing you how to:

| Default name | Renamed |
| --- | --- |
| posX.jpg | negX.jpg |
| negX.jpg | posX.jpg |
| posZ.jpg | negZ.jpg |
| negZ.jpg | posZ.jpg |

**And after renaming process, rotate `posY.jpg` and `negY.jpg` images by 180 degrees**.